# How do I reference the current iterator in a for loop in an excel formula using openpyxl?

Tags: python, loops, excel-formula, path, openpyxl

I have a list of files and a workbook template which will be used to produce additional workbooks with a specific content.

I want to reference the value of the cell N2 of every file in the for loop, on the 14th column of the template file.

My code currently throws the error :

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 5-6: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape.

In the past I used the raw string format, but due to the f string formatting and the formula syntax, it throws the above error.

```
wb = load_workbook(os.path.join(r"C:\Users\pallist\AROTRON_OUT","template.xlsx"))
sheet = wb.worksheets[0]
files = glob.glob(".xlsx")

for f in files :
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=sheet.max_row, min_col=14, max_col=14):
        for cell in row :
            partner    = f"=r'C:\Users\pallist\AROTRON_IN\{f}Sheet1'!$N$2)"
            cell.value = partner
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read through your question several times. Based on what I understand, below is what you are trying to do. Please correct if requirement is something else...

1. You have multiple input XLSX files in a folder `C:\Users\pallist\AROTRON_IN\`
2. You want to EACH xlsx file there and read the contents of Sheet1-Cell N2 -> N--max_row
3. You have another file C:\Users\pallist\AROTRON_OUT\template.xlsx - worksheet[0]. The N2->N_max_row data read in above step (for each input file) should be added to this file in cell A2, A3, A4.... the number of rows that are updated will be equal to the number of rows in the input file.
4. Save the template file as a new file in C:\Users\pallist\AROTRON_OUT\ folder with name equal to the input file name.
5. Repeat steps 2 - 4 for each excel file in the AROTRON_IN folder

See if this works... let me know in case of any issues

```
outpath = "C:\Users\pallist\AROTRON_OUT" ## Output path
inpath = "C:\Users\pallist\AROTRON_IN" ## Input path

files = glob.glob(os.path.join(inpath, "*.xlsx")) ## All INPUT files

for f in files :  ## For each input file
    fwb=load_workbook(f)  ## Open each input file
    fsheet=fwb['Sheet1']
    i=2
    wb = load_workbook(os.path.join(inpath, "template.xlsx"))
    sheet = wb.worksheets[0]
    for row in fsheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=fsheet.max_row, min_col=14, max_col=14): ##Read N2 - last row in INPUT file
        for cell in row :
            sheet.cell(row=i,column=1).value = cell.value
            i=i+1
    wb.save(os.path.join(outpath,os.path.basename(f)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. First of all, I need to create multiple excel files based on the template. Each new file will be the same as the template, except that all the cells of the column N will be populated with the value of the cell N2, from the current file in the for loop. So it would be like this : First new (based on template) file : N1 = f1  N2=f1 N3=f1, Second (based on template) file : N1 = f2  N2=f2 N3=f2 etc

Comment: Hi - I have updated the steps ONLY (no code change). Is this what you are trying to do? If ok, will update code

Comment: Yes, those are the exact steps, except that the number of rows that are updated will be equal to the number rows in the A column in the template file. Please note that in addition to that formula, I would like to apply this VLOOKUP formula VLOOKUP(A2,inputfileSheet1!A:P,16,0). But that is for later. Thank you

Comment: Check updated code

Comment: Hello, I tried your code and it works for the most part! Thanks! I will post another question which will include the full code I am working on, including the vlookup function.

Comment: Glad to hear that. If something is not working or needs to be fixed, do post here or as a new question

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the `r'` that's not being recognized inside the f-string that's causing the problem. Try the following code, see if it helps

```
vrb = pathlib.Path(r'C:\Users\pallist\AROTRON_IN')
for f in files:
    new_vrb = pathlib.Path.joinpath(vrb, f"{f}Sheet1!$N$2)")
    entry = "=" + str(new_vrb)
    print(entry)
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your code but it does not populate the excel file. Regardless, thank you for your input.

Comment: No problem. I wish you luck in solving your issue